# Is it possible to assign a jenkins pipeline to a variable and run in groovy script?

Tags: jenkins

I have a groovy script that defines a pipeline. The pipeline has several stages. I would like to assign that pipeline definition into a variable and run it later in the same groovy script. Is it possible?

I could not find a documentation on how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to describe can be done with a feature of the groovy programming language called [closures](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

Assuming you have a groovy script similar to this:

```
node() {
    stage('A') {
        println("I'm stage A!")
    }

    stage('B') {
        println("I'm stage B!")
    }
}
```

You could rerun this pipeline multiple times doing something like this:

```
node() {
    // Create the closure here
    def reusablePipeline = {
        node() {
            stage('A') {
                println("I'm stage A!")
            }

            stage('B') {
                println("I'm stage B!")
            }
        }
    }

    // Run the pipeline once
    reusablePipeline()

    // Run it a second time
    reusablePipeline()
}
```

If all the pipelines will run on the same `node()` than we can remove the second definition:

```
def reusablePipeline = {
    stage('A') {
        println("I'm stage A!")
    }

    stage('B') {
        println("I'm stage B!")
    }
}
```

If you find the reusable part of the job really long, you might want to load it from a second file instead. You can do this with the pipeline [load](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) function. Here is an example:

Put your reusable pipeline in a new file. Here I call it `pipeline.groovy`.

```
//contents of pipeline.groovy
def doStuff() {
    stage('A') {
        println("I'm stage A!")
    }

    stage('B') {
        println("I'm stage B!")
    }
}

// This is really important
return this
```

Now your pipeline would look something like this:

```
node() {
    def reusablePipeline = load('pipeline.groovy')

    // Run the pipeline once
    reusablePipeline.doStuff()

    // Run it a second time
    reusablePipeline.doStuff()
}
```

The above methods work great if you have a pipeline with a series of complicated steps and you would like to call those steps multiple times based on some criteria. A common use case is recalling a test suite with different parameters or re-running the test suite if some flaky tests fail.

But if you want to re-use pipeline steps across multiple Jenkins pipelines. Then you are looking for [Jenkins Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

I have a public shared library with lots of utilities to make writing pipelines easier called the [jenkins-std-lib](https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/jenkins-std-lib). I'm also the creator of the [Jenkins Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DontShaveTheYak.jenkins-extension-pack) which makes it easier to write Jenkins pipelines using the VSCode IDE.